# Hybris custom Category itemtype not syncing

Tags: categories, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I've created my own Itemtype extending Category:

```
<itemtype code="BrandCategory" extends="Category">
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="hide" type="java.lang.Boolean">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                    <defaultvalue>java.lang.Boolean.FALSE</defaultvalue>
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="false" search="true"/>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

However, when I assign this category to any Product that already has other categories and I do a catalog synchronization, all the categories do copy to online except the custom ones (BrandCategory).

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig and it can be done either via Backoffice or via Impex.

```
"#%groovy%
def query = '''SELECT {pk} FROM {<CustomJOBName>CatalogVersionSyncJob}'''
def syncJobs = flexibleSearchService.search(query).result

//forcing all sync jobs to create sync descriptors, if not created
syncJobs.each { syncJob -> syncJob.getSyncAttributeConfigurations() }
"

UPDATE GenericItem[processor = de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.ConfigPropertyImportProcessor]; pk[unique = true]
$attribute = attributeDescriptor(enclosingType(code), qualifier)[unique = true]

UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig[batchmode = true]; $attribute                ; includedInSync
                                                      ; BrandCategory:hide ; true

UPDATE AttributeDescriptor; enclosingType(code)[unique = true]; qualifier[unique = true]; unique
                          ; BrandCategory              ; catalogVersion          ; true
```

To run groovy in Impex, please add this property to local. properties.

## Disable legacy scripting (makes groovy work at impex)

impex.legacy.scripting=false

or run impex via enabling the code execution.
[image]

Comment: What is the value <CustomJOBName> ?

Comment: If you have custom item type which is extending CatalogVersionSyncJob.
if no then you can use CatalogVersionSyncJob

Comment: When I try to import It throws : ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] (000019JG) [CronJobErrorHandler] Exception ocurred, will ignore: de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: error executing code line at 1 : In file: inline evaluation of: ``groovy% def query = '''SELECT {pk} FROM {CatalogVersionSyncJob}''' def syncJobs  . . . '' Encountered "query" at line 2, column 5.

Comment: If I enable the code execution it stills throws me the same error, looks like the Groovy script doesn't parse or something.

Comment: then just remove groovy related part and execute normal impex

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the new type(i.e **BrandCategory**)  into your product synchronization job as a root type as depicted in below image:
[image]

Comment: It Throws: Caused by: de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloInvalidParameterException: found overlapping root types [] - root types must not be assignable from each other !

Comment: Ok, that means my suggestion was not the best since BrandCategory extends Category. Do you have any errors in logs ?